# Swipe gesture on Forms using SwipeBackSupport

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add a swipe gesture to move between forms. Here is what I have already done:

```
Form startForm = new Form("START FORM");
Form secondForm = new Form("SECOND FORM"); //I want to grant access to other forms from this one

//We cann access to other forms using the buttons
Button btnToStartForm = new Button("Go to startForm");
Button btnToThirdForm = new Button("Go to thirdForm");

secondForm.add(btnToStartForm).add(btnToThirdForm);

Form thirdForm = new Form("THIRD FORM");


LazyValue<Form> lazyStartForm = new LazyValue<Form>() {
    @Override
    public Form get(Object... args) {
        return startForm;
    }
};
LazyValue<Form> lazySecondForm = new LazyValue<Form>() {
    @Override
    public Form get(Object... args) {
        return secondForm;
    }
};
LazyValue<Form> lazyThirdForm = new LazyValue<Form>() {
    @Override
    public Form get(Object... args) {               
        return thirdForm;
    }
};

//At first, we can use swipe gesture to go from start to second, from second to start or from third to second
SwipeBackSupport.bindBack(startForm, lazySecondForm);
SwipeBackSupport.bindBack(thirdForm, lazySecondForm);
SwipeBackSupport.bindBack(secondForm, lazyStartForm); // For this one I would like to swipe from right to left

//When I click on a button I want to update the target of the swipeBackSupport in the second Form but it doesn't work
//I want to swipe from the second form to the last showed form 
btnToStartForm.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        startForm.show();
        SwipeBackSupport.bindBack(secondForm, lazyStartForm);
    }
});
btnToThirdForm.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        thirdForm.show();
        SwipeBackSupport.bindBack(secondForm, lazyThirdForm);
    }
});

startForm.show();
```

The second Form gives access to the startForm and to the thirdForm. At first we can use the swipe gesture to go from from start to second and from second to start.
  The second has also buttons that let us go to the startForm and to the thirdForm. When we use the buttons, I would like to update the target Form of the second form swipe gesture.
 I also would like to use the swipe gesture from right to left.
 Maybe I am not using the SwipebackBackSupport correctly ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working from the description. Swiping from right to left isn't supported but what's the failure with the regular usage?

Comment: With the regular usage, I need to update the targeted form of the gesture:
I bind the first form to the second form and the second to the first one. When I go on the second form, I click on a button that shoul bind the second form to the third form. But when I do that, it's still binded to the first form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `SwipeBackSupport` doesn't include support for changing the binding after the binding was made so you still get a call to the old binding.

While this can probably be fixed the official way of doing this is to use the lazy value properly which is why it's a lazy value. We assume you won't know the actual form you want to bind to which is  why lazy value can return a form determined at runtime...